# Delphi and OpenGL - simple example

Tags: delphi, opengl, draw

I'm trying to create some basic application in Delphi and OpenGL. I'll need to draw some 2D images on the screen.

Here is my code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, OpenGL;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormResize(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    GLContext : HGLRC;
    glDC: HDC;
    errorCode: GLenum;
    openGLReady: Boolean;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  pfd: TPixelFormatDescriptor;
  FormatIndex: Integer;
begin
  FillChar(pfd,SizeOf(pfd),0);
  with pfd do
  begin
    nSize := SizeOf(pfd);
    nVersion := 1; {The current version of the desccriptor is 1}
    dwFlags := PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW or PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL;
    iPixelType := PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    cColorBits := 24; {support 24-bit color}
    cDepthBits := 32; {depth of z-axis}
    iLayerType := PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
  end;
  glDC := getDC(handle);
  FormatIndex := ChoosePixelFormat(glDC,@pfd);
  SetPixelFormat(glDC,FormatIndex,@pfd);
  GLContext := wglCreateContext(glDC);
  wglMakeCurrent(glDC,GLContext);
  OpenGLReady := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  wglMakeCurrent(Canvas.Handle,0);
  wglDeleteContext(GLContext);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not openGLReady then
    exit;
  {background}
  glClearColor(0.1,0.0,0.1,0.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glLoadIdentity; // Reset The View
  glTranslatef(0.0, 0, 0.0);
  glRotateF (360, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  glBegin( GL_POLYGON ); // start drawing a polygon
    glColor3f( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f( 0.0, 0.5, 0.0 ); // Top
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, 0.0 ); // Bottom Right
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, 0.0 ); // Bottom Left
  glEnd;
  glFlush;
  {error checking}
  errorCode:=glGetError;
   if errorCode<>GL_NO_ERROR then
      raise Exception.Create('Error in Paint'#13+gluErrorString(errorCode));
  SwapBuffers(wglGetCurrentDC);
  glFlush();
end;

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not openGLReady then
  exit;
  glViewPort(0,0,ClientWidth,ClientHeight);
  glOrtho(-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0);
  errorCode := glGetError;
  if errorCode<>GL_NO_ERROR then
  raise Exception.Create('FormResize:'+gluErrorString(errorCode));
end;

procedure GLInit;
begin
  // set viewing projection
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glFrustum(-0.1, 0.1, -0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 15.0);
  // position viewer
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
end;

end.
```

Everything works without errors, but at the end I don't get a dark green form. The form stays the same (grey).

What is wrong with this?

I've started app from IDE and as standalone app. I'm using Delphi 10.4 and Windows 10. I've checked and opengl32.dll is in System32 folder.

Comment: You are never calling `GLInit`!

Comment: Also, you are using the legacy (fixed) OpenGL pipeline from the 1990s. That's very obsolete. You should be using the modern programmable pipeline.

Comment: Now I've checked and GLInit is code from other example that shouldn't be there. Init should be done in Form Create event. That should work without that.

Comment: At the very least you need to make sure you are in `GL_PROJECTION` matrix mode when you do `glOrtho(-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0);` and in `GL_MODELVIEW` mode every time you work with the objects in the scene. Your code cannot function without at least a couple of calls to `glMatrixMode`.

Comment: SDL uses OpenGL or D2D, Pascal units are available on https://github.com/PascalGameDevelopment/SDL2-for-Pascal

Comment: OK now I've placed call to GLInit at the beginnig of the FormCreate, FormResize and FormPaint event handlers. Still no result. I need basic example that is working. I'm lost now.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your code. First, you never call your `GLInit` procedure, so you never set up your projection matrix. Also, `GLInit` uses `glFrustum`, while your form resize handler uses `glOrtho`. Which do you want?

I found a very old OpenGL example app I made a couple of decades ago, which you may study (here in slightly modernised form):

```pascal
unit mainWin;

interface

uses
  OpenGL, Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, Math;

type

  TBall = record
    x, phi: Double;
  end;

  TmainFrm = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer; // 25 ms
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Integer);
    procedure FormResize(Sender: TObject);
    procedure WMEraseBkGnd(var Message:TMessage); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
  private
    Angle: Double;
    Balls: array[0..100] of TBall;
    BallIndex: Integer;
    procedure InitGL;
  end;

var
  mainFrm: TmainFrm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TmainFrm.InitGL;
const
  pfd: TPixelFormatDescriptor = (
    nSize: SizeOf(TPixelFormatDescriptor);
    nVersion: 1;
    dwFlags: PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL or PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW or PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    iPixelType: PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    cColorBits: 32;
    cRedBits: 0; cRedShift: 0;
    cGreenBits: 0;  cGreenShift: 0;
    cBlueBits: 0; cBlueShift: 0;
    cAlphaBits: 0;  cAlphaShift: 0;
    cAccumBits: 0;
    cAccumRedBits: 0;
    cAccumGreenBits: 0;
    cAccumBlueBits: 0;
    cAccumAlphaBits: 0;
    cDepthBits: 24;
    cStencilBits: 0;
    cAuxBuffers: 0;
    iLayerType: PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
    bReserved: 0;
    dwLayerMask: 0;
    dwVisibleMask: 0;
    dwDamageMask: 0;
  );

begin
  var DC := GetDC(Handle);
  var PixelFormat := ChoosePixelFormat(DC, @pfd);
  if PixelFormat = 0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  if not SetPixelFormat(DC, PixelFormat, @pfd) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  var RC := wglCreateContext(DC);
  if RC = 0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  wglMakeCurrent(DC, RC);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
  glPointSize(10);
  glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
  FormResize(Self);
end;

procedure TmainFrm.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
const
  p1: TGLArrayf3 = (-5, -5, -1);
  p2: TGLArrayf3 = (5, -5, -1);
  p3: TGLArrayf3 = (0, 5, -1);
begin

  if Tag = 0 then
  begin
    InitGL;
    Tag := 1;
  end;

  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity;

  glColor3ub(255, 255, 255);
  glRotate(Angle, 0, 0, 1);
  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
  glVertex3fv(@p1); glVertex3fv(@p2); glVertex3fv(@p3);
  glEnd;
  glRotate(-Angle, 0, 0, 1);

  glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);

  for var i := Low(Balls) to High(Balls) do
  begin
    if (Balls[i].x = 0) or (Balls[i].x > 100) then
      Continue;
    glRotate(Balls[i].phi, 0, 0, 1);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex3f(0, Balls[i].x, -1);
    glEnd;
    glRotate(-Balls[i].phi, 0, 0, 1);
  end;

  SwapBuffers(wglGetCurrentDC);

end;

procedure TmainFrm.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  glViewport(0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  const AR = ClientWidth / Max(ClientHeight, 1);
  glLoadIdentity;
  glOrtho(-15*AR, 15*AR, -15, 15, 0.5, 25.0);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
end;

procedure TmainFrm.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin

  for var i := Low(Balls) to High(Balls) do
    if Balls[i].x <> 0 then
      Balls[i].x := Balls[i].x + 1;

  if csLButtonDown in ControlState then // Add new ball
  begin
    Balls[BallIndex].x := 5;
    Balls[BallIndex].phi := Angle;
    BallIndex := Succ(BallIndex) mod Length(Balls);
  end;

  Invalidate;

end;

procedure TmainFrm.WMEraseBkGnd(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Message.Result := 1;
end;

procedure TmainFrm.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  Angle := ArcTan2(-Y + ClientHeight div 2, X - ClientWidth div 2) * 180 / Pi + 270;
end;

end.
```

[image: Video of program running]

However, please note the adjective *old*. Today, you shouldn't use the fixed pipeline API at all.

Comment: Original code that I've posted is working. I haven't seen any changes because I was using RD. Now I feel so stupid. :-( Andreas you were right. I'm sorry for wasting your time.
Now I'm trying to draw png image using texture. No luck for now, but I continue to work on this. I must check your remarks about fixed pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

Great, now I have a working code that I can study. Thank you Andreas.
I've run this code on my laptop (my IDE is in an Oracle Virtual Box VM) and it is working. It is also working my PC. It doesn't work on my other VM that is under VMware.
I'm getting an error in debug mode (nothing is drawn on the form):

onecore\windows\directx\database\helperlibrary\lib\directxdatabasehelper.cpp(663)\dxgi.dll!6F17C233: (caller: 6F17BE20) ReturnHr(2) tid(162c) 80070057 The parameter is incorrect.

I'think that is because on that VM VDDM is version 1.3.

That may be a reason that I was not able to get any example code working.

That problem is on the line "SwapBuffers(wglGetCurrentDC);".

One thing is strange that after I compile that working code and run it again on my PC where it was working before it doesn't work.

But that is another issue. I've something to start with it.

Comment: I think the problem is that you need to recreate the OpenGL context if the window (HWND) is recreated. You probably will see the same error if you switch a running app to/from a remote desktop session. I omitted that complication in the my sample app (or maybe I wasn't even aware about it 20 years ago!), but in a real app, you must take window recreation into account. But this is a different topic, related to many things not OpenGL.

Comment: Actually, you can see that I override `CreateWnd` in https://algosim.org/SynViewSource/rgl.html.